# Initial page load (and page refresh) renders incorrect component using React-Media and Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm in need of help here. I'm creating a portfolio for a friend using Next.js, and the issue I'm trying to troubleshoot is the initial page load of the index page. In my local/dev environment, the first initial page load renders the mobile layout component (see code below) for a moment before it renders the desktop layout component (a bug). Now, after deploying the app to a hosted server with the provided link -
https://chezportfolio-mdirmhphih.now.sh/
The page only loads and maintains the mobile layout which is incorrect. The layout corrects itself after navigating to other routes and back. Also, I am using React-Media to render specific components based on media queries. I'm not entirely sure what's triggering the issue but my guess is the SSR capabilities of Next.js does not mesh well with React-Media.

The link to my repository is listed below if you need to deep dive further-
[Link to Repo](https://github.com/philmein23/chez_portfolio/blob/chez_portfolio/pages/index.js)

EDIT: I am still stuck on this issue, and really cannot progress further until this is resolved.

```
export default class Index extends Component {
      static async getInitialProps() {
        const options = {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors'
        };

        const resources = await fetch(CLOUDINARY('chez').URL, options);
        const imageData = await resources.json();

        return {
          imageData
        };
      }

          componentDidMount() {
            console.log(this.props);
          }

      render() {
        const { url, imageData } = this.props;

        const belowMaxWidth = () => {
          return (
            <Content maxWidth={300} margin={'120px auto'}>
              <Images imageData={imageData} width={300} />
            </Content>
          );
        };

        const aboveMaxWidth = () => {
          return (
            <Content>
              <Images imageData={imageData} width={200} />
            </Content>
          );
        };

        return (
          <Layout href={url.pathname}>
            <Media query="(max-width: 575px)" render={belowMaxWidth} />
            <Media query="(min-width: 574px)" render={aboveMaxWidth} />
          </Layout>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: My first guess is that next.js renders the mobile layout first because there is no DOM or no Window available to get a media query size from. The next issue is that onComponentWillmount or ComponentDidMount its not triggering a reRender to get the current size of the window. With CSS this would be instant but it sounds like some JS is also getting in the way of calculating the window properly.